# Android Get json response of website call

Tags: android, word-wrap

there are some some web site that call end point and recive a json response.
I would like to know how in myAndroid app i can call the web site and retrive the json data that he show.
Example: this is a drivenow site map

[drivenow map link](https://it.drive-now.com/#!/carsharing/copenhagen)

if i open debug mode of browser i see this ajax call that give a josn response.
I would like to know i can call this website and take (grap) this response in my android app so i can use the json 
Any idea? Help?
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to get the URL of the web service using your browser developer tools. (you probably need authorization from the website to use their web service)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform GET/POST request using two ways.

## Some 3rd party network request libraries

I would suggest using robospice. Using robospice you perform a network request and give it a POJO. For more info on POJO refer to the link below

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide

[What is RoboSpice Library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087079/what-is-robospice-library-in-android)

## Using native Android/Java code

Use this function to get JSON from URL.

```
public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromURL(String urlString) throws IOException, JSONException {

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

URL url = new URL(urlString);

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

urlConnection.connect();

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

char[] buffer = new char[1024];

String jsonString = new String();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line+"\n");
}
br.close();

jsonString = sb.toString();

System.out.println("JSON: " + jsonString);

return new JSONObject(jsonString);}
```

Then use it like this:

```
try{
  JSONObject jsonObject = getJSONObjectFromURL(String urlString);

  // Parse your json here

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do not forget to add Internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For more info on parsing JSON visit 
[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

## Note

You don't have to manually parse your json if you use a 3rd party library.